# Convert to Managed BitLocker

Tags: bitlocker

I've been setting up an encryption policy using MBAM; after some trial-and-error, I finally got it working!  Adding new laptops is a **breeze**!  **However**...

I have several laptops that were encrypten using BitLocker (and they're reporting to the MBAM Console), but I can't manage the TPM password since they're not "owned" by the server.  Anybody know of a way to get these few laptops integrated into my MBAM console?

Comment: How about unencrypting them and then managing them with MBAM?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, if I could.  But, if that's the only way, then I'll hafta suck it up :-)

Comment: @joeqwerty: From what I've been reading I don't think unencrypting them is necessary to point them to the MBAM server is it?

Comment: Is this still a problem?